# Row Delete Loop in Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to "automatically" cleanup several worksheets with this simple code below. The code works if I only have one item in my array but as soon as I put two or more it deletes everything on the last item ("TestMA" in this case).

```
Dim SheetsArray As Sheets
Set SheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("TestCS", "TestMA"))
For Each msheets In SheetsArray
    With msheets

    i = 8
    Do While i < 600
        If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
            Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp   '''''HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            i = i - 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop  

    End With
Next msheets
```

I have determined that the problem is with the Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp line.

Help!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp   '''''HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

Use

```
.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp   '''''NOTE THE INITIAL PERIOD
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me.. Didn't seem to change anything.